# MySQL connector in python: insert row error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I have a table "persons" in database "testdb". The following shows up when executing the following in the mysql command line:

```
SELECT * FROM persons;
+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+
| PersonID | LastName | FirstName | Address        | City        |
+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+
|        1 | Angelil  | Oliver    | Farbstrasse    | Zurich      |
|        2 | Herger   | Nadja     | schoggistrasse | Unteraegeri |
|        3 | Kopparla | Pushkar   | shortstreet    | Banglore    |
|        4 | Herger   | Michael   | bananastreet   | cambridge   |
+----------+----------+-----------+----------------+-------------+
```

If I want to insert a new row, I would use:

```
INSERT INTO persons
  VALUES (5, 'Smith', 'John', 'longstreet', 'Paris');
```

I now want to do the same in Python with:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='elephant', password='password',
                              host='zoo.ddns.net',
                              database='testdb')

cursor = cnx.cursor()
insert = ("INSERT INTO persons"
                "VALUES (5, 'Smith', 'John', 'longstreet', 'Paris')")

cursor.execute(insert)
cnx.close()
```

But I'm getting the error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5, 'Smith',
>   'John', 'longstreet', 'Paris')' at line 1

Other commands like the following do work, so it's not an issue with the connection settings:

```
query = ("SELECT * FROM persons")
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: You need a space after persons or before VALUES. `insert` as you have it would hold: `"INSERT INTO personsVALUES (5, 'Smith', 'John', 'longstreet', 'Paris')"` which is why you get a syntax error.